# Trying to change the color of a button onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to development, so please forgive my lack of knowledge. I am trying to change the background color of a button that on a page that I am making. I have created something similar.

On this example I would like to change the background color to red when the date is on, and green when the date is off.

Please explain what I've done wrong here

```
    <!doctype>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Button in Java Script.</h1>
<p>Please click the button to display the date.</p>

<!=========this is button=============>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="on" style=background-color:#32CD32>Turn on Date</button>
<p id="demo"></p>


<!==== this is the button that will show the date====>
<script>
function myFunction(){
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var onoff= document.getElementById("on");
if (x.innerText=="")
{
    x.innerHTML = Date(); n = "Turn Date Off"; onoff.bgcolor="#FF0000"} 
    else {
    x.innerHTML =""; n = "Turn Date On"; onoff.bgcolor= "#32CD32"}

    onoff.innerText = n; }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

please be advised that I copied this code from W3schools and then edited it.

Answer (score 1):

For changing the background-color of element you can use this.

```
onoff.style.background ="#FF0000"
```

instead of

```
onoff.bgcolor="#FF0000"
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agHaL/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the syntax for changing the color from:

```
onoff.bgcolor = "#FF0000"
onoff.bgcolor = "#32CD32"
```

to:

```
onoff.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"
onoff.style.backgroundColor = "#32CD32"
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pcC67/)**